# Storing game states and scores in keychain

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I am trying to store some strings (scores, lastPlayedLevel, etc) of my game in keychain. Because it is said to be the most safe method. 
Since I am new to Keychain concept I have problems in understanding probably "very simple" things.

I use SAMKeychain wrapper and I want to set lastPlayedLevel string as below

```
[SAMKeychain setPassword:@"25" forService:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier] account:@"lastPlayedLevel"];
```

Is it a correct approach? I am not sure about the "account" part. I want "lastPlayedLevel" be synced across all devices of the user. Do I have to write a user specific string instead?

Comment: *Game scores and states* are not really qualified to be stored into the keychain. iOS is pretty safe by default. Save that kind of information into `UserDefaults`, a custom property list file or Core Data.

Comment: I didn't get why they are not qualified for keychain. There are many posts saying that UserDefaults are not safe to put sensitive info. For example in my game "score" determine many  aspects of the game so I don't want anybody access and modify it. I don't know much about custom plist file and core data, are they safe? Also with keychain it is possible to sync these info across multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting score and game state in keychain is overkill IMHO. What you need to do is just store them in the NSUserDefaults, but encode your data into binary before storing it so anybody opening your NSUSerDefaults file wont be able to view/edit it straight away. If you want more secrecy, then encode the value first (for example char xor or other) before encoding to binary.